# jQuery parse html and change it

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I parse an html string in jquery and change a specific element without loading it into the "normal" DOM.

What is not working:

- // 3. the border is applied to any element, not only on the
  contentContainer element
- // 4. the full content is loaded into the #outputContainer and not only the #contentContainer

This is my .html File:

```
<body>
  <h1>Title</h1>

  <div id="outputContainer">
  AAAAAAAAA
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is my .js File:

```
var html = '<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body>   <h1>HTML DOC</h1> ' 
            + '  <div id="contentContainer">     <ul> ' 
      + '  <li><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></li> ' 
      + '  <li><a href="http://www.netflix.com">netflix</a></li> ' 
   + '  </ul>   </div> '
   + ' <div><ul><li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">dont show yahoo</a></li></ul></div>' 
   + '</body> </html> ';


// 1. Parse HTML
var parsedHtml = $.parseHTML( html );

// 2. get contentContainer from parsed html
var contentFromParsedHTML =  $(parsedHtml, "#contentContainer");


// 3. change contentContainer from parsed html
$( contentFromParsedHTML, "#contentContainer").css( "border", "3px solid red" ); // not working

// 4. display changed contentContainer
$("#outputContainer").html(contentFromParsedHTML, "#contentContainer");
```

You can find this code on js fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/9ordytj7/

Comment: you can define a class in css (.red-border) and add it in the html string like so : 
` ... <div id="contentContainer" class="red-border"> .....` and the class would be
.red-border{ border: red solid 3px}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `parseHTML` returns an array and `.css` operates on the whole collection.

You can do this:

```
var contentFromParsedHTML =  $(parsedHtml).filter("#contentContainer");
contentFromParsedHTML.css( "border", "3px solid red" );
$("#outputContainer").html(contentFromParsedHTML);
```